# Is there any way to resize google chrome tabs with a custom value?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

The problem is seems simple, but I'm having trouble finding a solution on my own. I would like to resize browser tabs so that only the favicon is displayed, that is, all tabs would be small and take up little space (preferably so that they look like pinned tabs, but at the same time they can be used in groups, as pinned tabs leave groups).

I've been digging in the Chrome API but haven't found anything useful there, except for the chrome.tabs.Tab section, which has a width property, but as I understand it, it doesn't allow you to change the size values, only to get the values set by the browser itself (I understand a bit of the code, however I'm a beginner, so there's a high probability that I'm just misunderstanding something).

I found pretty much what I need but for Firefox:

*1. Create the file %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles*\chrome\userChrome.css.*

*2. Set its contents to*

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned]) {
    max-width: 4000px !important;
}
```

*3. Restart Firefox for the change to take effect.*

There's a pretty simple css there that would solve my problem, because I could specify a maximum tab size of a couple dozen pixels, and that would be enough.
However, I couldn't find anything similar for Chrome.

I'm interested in any ways to solve this problem, so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no solution for Chrome. It doesn't provide any way to customize the tab area.